# Redis using 100% CPU after 6 hours of uptime

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

[image]

As seen in the image above, I'm experiencing performance issues with Redis after it has been running for an extended period of time; specially, 6 hours.

I'm using Redis to cache responses from an API so I don't have to re-fetch dozens of rows on every request, and I thought - hey this should work. Apparently not.

```
module.exports = (app, csrfProtection, jsonParser) => {
    app.get("/api/steam/getPlayerSummaries", [steamRateLimits.getPlayerSummaries, jsonParser, csrfProtection], async(req, res) => {
        redisClient.hmget("steam_user", req.query.steamids, (err, reply) => {
            if(err) return res.status(500).send({ message: `Could not read from Redis with error ${err}`});

            redisClient.hmget(`steam_user_expires_${req.query.steamids}`, "expires", (err, expire) => {
                if(err) return res.status(500).send({ message: `Could not read from Redis with error ${err}`});

                if(reply[0] && (CURRENT_UNIX_TIME - expire < REDIS_EXPIRE_LIMIT)) return res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(reply));

                const queryParams = querystring.stringify({
                    key: process.env.STEAM_API_KEY,
                    steamids: req.query.steamids
                }),
                options = {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    }
                };

                http.get(`http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?${queryParams}`, options, response => {
                    const { statusCode } = response;

                    if(statusCode != 200) {
                        response.resume();
                        return res.status(statusCode).send({ message: `Could not fetch Steam API getPlayerSummaries with status code ${statusCode}`});
                    }

                    response.setEncoding("utf8");
                    let rawData = "";

                    response.on("data", chunk => rawData += chunk);
                    response.on("end", _ => {
                        try {
                            const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);

                            redisClient.hmset(["steam_user", req.query.steamids, rawData]);
                            redisClient.hmset([`steam_user_expires_${req.query.steamids}`, "expires", CURRENT_UNIX_TIME]);

                            return res.status(200).send(parsedData);
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.error(e.message);
                        }
                    });
                }).on("error", e => {
                    console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
                    return res.status(500).send(e);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Here's the progress overview of what happens in chronological order when a user tries to access this route:

1. User loads the index (default) webpage. This page can have over 20
   rows that need to run 20 API queries from the remote API (one of the
   reasons I cache this).
2. Check if user is already cached in redis
3. Check if there exists an expiration key for said steam user (even if it doesn't exist).
4. If cache exists and it was fetched in less than 15 minutes ago, display result from Redis cache.
5. If cache doesn't exist, we query the remote API.
6. If request was successful, cache data into Redis and return response.

For some reason this gets caught up in itself and after some time running Redis uses so much CPU and RAM it's insane and I thought I was dealing with this properly.

I am also clearing ALL cache once a day using a shell script and crontab.

```
redis-cli KEYS "steam_user*" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

Why does it continue to use up more CPU and RAM (even if there is literally no visitors, and I'm scared to think what would happen if there were a lot of visitors), and how can I work around this issue to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process that is using all your resources is /tmp/kdevtmpfsi. A quick google search showed that it's mining malware. This means that not Redis nor your program has some kind of error. [This](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/217#issuecomment-569623314) comment on Github explains how to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not even using docker and it's a fresh server from vultr. Really surprised someone managed to find it so quick.